# Recursively generate combinations with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I  am trying to provide a recursive method that provides a list of all the possible combinations when given a list of courses. E.g course = [Entree, Dessert]
This is what I have so far:

```
Entree = ["pumkinsoup","antipasto"]
Dessert = ["cheesecake", "icecream", "tiramisu", "cheeseplatter"]
courses = [Entree, Dessert]

def make_orders(courses):
    dishes_so_far = []
    recursive_make_orders(dishes_so_far, courses)

def recursive_make_orders(dishes_so_far, courses):
    n = len(courses)
    if n==0 :
        print(dishes_so_far)
    else:
        current_courses = courses[0]

        for D in current_courses:
            dishes_so_far.append(D)
            recursive_make_orders(dishes_so_far , courses[1:len(courses)])
```

\I am trying to make it so that it prints out the combination like `[[pumkinsoup,cheesecake],[punkinsoup, icecream]]` and etc but its actually giving me `[pumkinsoup, cheesecake, icecream]` and so on.

Tried adding it with addition instead of append and it gave me an error.

This is homework, so a recursive method is required.

Comment: Please be more detailed in what you want to accomplish. Example output is fine, but not enough. And don't post your attempt to solve it here. It's distracting and not fun to dissect it. I think this explains downvotes.

Comment: @ash actually I disagree - while some may find it distracting, a genuine attempt to solve the problem is more than welcome and is in fact encouraged by the community. No one likes "gimme teh codez" questions...

Comment: @ash: What? I thought http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ was the approach here on SO?

Comment: You've convinced me. I retract the last part of my comment.

Comment: After the line `dishes_so_far.append(D)` , print `courses, current_courses, dishes_so_far` to see their  contents before you call `recursive_make_orders(dishes_so_far , courses[1:len(courses)])`

Comment: the final answer is :['pumkinsoup', 'cheesecake', 'icecream', 'tiramisu', 'antipasto', 'cheesecake', 'icecream', 'tiramisu', 'potato twist', 'cheesecake', 'icecream', 'tiramisu']
['pumkinsoup', 'cheesecake', 'icecream', 'tiramisu', 'antipasto', 'cheesecake', 'icecream', 'tiramisu', 'potato twist', 'cheesecake', 'icecream', 'tiramisu']

Comment: @user2784327so *I guess* there is a problem about your lists. May be you are doing something wrong about them.

Answer (score 2):

You're not too far off - use `itertools.product` and `*courses` to unpack to it:

```
from itertools import product

for course in product(*courses):
  print course

('pumkinsoup', 'cheesecake')
('pumkinsoup', 'icecream')
('pumkinsoup', 'tiramisu')
('pumkinsoup', 'cheeseplatter')
('antipasto', 'cheesecake')
('antipasto', 'icecream')
('antipasto', 'tiramisu')
('antipasto', 'cheeseplatter')
```

Comment: sorry i should have stated that recursive method needs to be used, according to the question i have been given

Comment: @JonClements List comprehension  would be probably more pythonic ;)`[[entree, desert] for entree in Entree for desert in Dessert]`

Comment: @JonClements True, although if I remember correctly, itertools have problems of it's own.

Answer (score 1):

If you want recursive version, you can do something like this:

```
def worker(entree, dessert):
    d = []
    if not entree or not dessert: return d

    d.append((entree[0], dessert[0]))
    d += worker(entree[1:], dessert)
    d += worker(entree, dessert[1:])
    return d
```

Your version is not working as you said because `courses` now a list of lists, and `courses[0]` is just `Entree`, so you recursively constructiong new list from `Entree`.